# mySQL import / duplicate keys

Tags: mysql, import, primary-key

I am writing a database that needs to be able to import information from another database.  My database has a table for members and another table for permissions that members may be granted (a member may be granted more than one type of permission).  The members table contains a column to store the primary key for members from the other DB for the purpose of smooth imports.

My problem is that when I import the other DB key and permission from the other database then turn the "other keys" into my keys, I am likely duplicating entries in the permissions table, which mySQL correctly will not allow.  I would like it to go ahead and change the ones it can and I know the ones that are not changed I can delete.

Can someone help me, or have an altogether different solution?

Comment: If you are deleting the duplicate ones anyway, why don't you just use insert ignore and only migrate the non duplicates?

Comment: When I do the original import, I am using a client that is importing a .csv and I don't think I can tell it to substitute the correct foreign key for the other key.  Then I would like to use a query like this:
UPDATE GRANTED,MEMBERS SET GRANTED.MEM_ID = MEMBERS.MEM_ID WHERE GRANTED.MEM_ID = MEMBERS.MEM_SK_ID
This update worked the first time, and I was hoping it would do everything it could and just leave the rest.

Comment: Even better, if you have it in a CSV, just use `LOAD DATA INFILE ...` and duplicates are automatically ignored.

Comment: I imported the file to a tabled called TEMP, then ran this query.  INSERT INTO GRANTED (MEM_ID,PERM_CODE)
 SELECT MEMBERS.MEM_ID AS MEM_ID,PERM_CODE
 FROM MEMBERS JOIN TEMP ON (MEMBERS.MEM_SK_ID=TEMP.MEM_ID)
 WHERE (MEMBERS.MEM_ID,PERM_CODE) NOT IN (SELECT MEM_ID,PERM_CODE FROM GRANTED);

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `IGNORE` to your query and lose the `not in`. Duplicate errors are then regarded as warnings and your import will continue with just the unique data. You don't need to comeback and delete the duplicates by hand.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO GRANTED (MEM_ID,PERM_CODE) 
SELECT MEMBERS.MEM_ID AS MEM_ID,PERM_CODE 
FROM MEMBERS 
JOIN TEMP
ON (MEMBERS.MEM_SK_ID=TEMP.MEM_ID)
```